# Swift4, successor()

Tags: swift

How to implement `successor()` to Swift4, Swift5?

```
func withMask(mask: String) -> String {
    var resultString = String()

    let chars = self
    let maskChars = mask

    var stringIndex = chars.startIndex
    var maskIndex = mask.startIndex

    while stringIndex < chars.endIndex && maskIndex < maskChars.endIndex {
        if (maskChars[maskIndex] == "#") {
            resultString.append(chars[stringIndex])
            stringIndex = stringIndex.successor()
        } else {
            resultString.append(maskChars[maskIndex])
        }
        maskIndex = maskIndex.successor()
    }

    return resultString
}
```

> Value of type 'String.Index' has no member 'successor'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Swift 3+ equivalent of `successor()` is `index(after`

```
stringIndex = chars.index(after: stringIndex)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is all incredibly convoluted. Just user `zip` and `map`:

```
extension String {
    func masked(using mask: String) -> String {
        let newChars = zip(self, mask).map { sourceChar, maskChar in
            return (maskChar == "#") ? "#" : sourceChar
        }

        return String(newChars)
    }
}
```

Although using a String of characters, whose characters encode booleans (true if `#` otherwise false) probably isn't a great idea. Better to just use an `IndexSet`.